# Why passing a Bytes to a function leads to lifetime error, even though it's guaranteed to complete before drop? and how to fix?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

My current code using `bytes` crate:

```
pub async fn send_msg(online_users: Arc<Mutex<OnlineUsers>>, msg: &Message, from: &str) -> io::Result<()> {
    let target_user = msg.args.get(0).ok_or(io::Error::from(io::ErrorKind::InvalidInput))?;
    if let Content::Text(ref text) = msg.content {
        let text_owned = text.clone();
        let text_byte = Bytes::from(text_owned.as_bytes());
        let mut online_users = online_users.lock().await;
        online_users.send_to_user(target_user, text_byte).await; 
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

The error occurs at the call of send_to_user(), the definition of it is:

```
pub async fn send_to_user(&mut self, name: &str, content: Bytes) -> io::Result<()> {
    let target_user = self
        .list
        .get_mut(name)
        .ok_or(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::NotConnected, name.clone()))?;
    target_user.send(content).await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Error message below:

```
error[E0597]: `text_owned` does not live long enough
  --> server/src/handler.rs:28:37
   |
28 |         let text_byte = Bytes::from(text_owned.as_bytes());
   |                         ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                         |           |
   |                         |           borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                         argument requires that `text_owned` is borrowed for `'static`
...
31 |     }
   |     - `text_owned` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I do not understand why it does not live long enough. Since I called .await on an `send_to_user()`, it must complete before `send_msg()` reaches its end and drop all variables.
I want:

1. explanation why this happens.
2. how am I able to fix this?

Comment: I am sorry for not specifying that, I thought `bytes` crate is the de facto only option.

Comment: I've just done that, thanks for asking.  : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bytes::from` is implemented for [`&'static [u8]`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/struct.Bytes.html#impl-From%3C%26%27static%20%5Bu8%5D%3E-for-Bytes), whereas `String::as_bytes` does not give you a static reference. You must provide some owned data structure to `Bytes::from`. I'd opt for passing your `text_owned` variable directly, as `Bytes` implements [`From<String>`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/struct.Bytes.html#impl-From%3CString%3E-for-Bytes):

```rust
pub async fn send_msg(online_users: Arc<Mutex<OnlineUsers>>, msg: &Message, from: &str) -> io::Result<()> {
    let target_user = msg.args.get(0).ok_or(io::Error::from(io::ErrorKind::InvalidInput))?;
    if let Content::Text(ref text) = msg.content {
        let text_owned = text.clone();
        let text_byte = Bytes::from(text_owned);
        let mut online_users = online_users.lock().await;
        online_users.send_to_user(target_user, text_byte).await; 
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: It works if I change the signature of send_to_user by changing the parameter type to String. This answer solves my problem, but I wonder if there exists another way that keeps func signature unchanged.

Comment: Are you passing `text_owned` directly? Could you try `online_users.send_to_user(target_user, Bytes::from(text.clone()))`? You'd still provide a `Bytes` struct and wouldn't have to change your API

Comment: Ah I see... Yes your code works!!